# Plotly R Custom Contours (multiple colorscales)

Tags: r, plot, plotly, contour

I have 6 different data tables, namely `df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6`.

I'm trying to create one big figure that contains 6 contour plots for each data table. Here are some specifications for each df:

- min(df1$z) = 10, max(df1$z) = 40
- min(df2$z) = 52, max(df2$z) = 138
- min(df3$z) = 131, max(df3$z) = 333
- min(df4$z) = 41, max(df4$z) = 173
- min(df5$z) = 103, max(df5$z) = 216
- min(df6$z) = 182, max(df6$z) = 387

Each table has 10000 rows with all different z values.

I wanted to use a single colorscale (or legend) that can be applied to all 6 data tables. So for each contour plot, I specified the start and end of the contour like below.

For `df1`: `df1_plot <- plot_ly(x = df1$x, y = df1$y, z = df1$z, type = 'contour', autocontour = F, colorscale = 'Greens', contours = list(start = 10, end = 400, ncontours = 25)`

However, the problem is that the `z` values in `df1` are too small, compared to those in `df6`. So when I plot for `df1`, I simply get a plot with no contours at all like the picture below:
[image]

To solve this issue, I am thinking to aggregate multiple colorscales. For example, dark blue to light blue for 0 - 50, light blue to green for 50 - 100, green to yellow for 100 - 150, yellow to orange for 150 - 200, and so on. Another example can be the picture below:

[image]

How can I achieve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why the plot is empty and how changing the colors could solve this problem. But regarding your question, you can do something like

```r
colorscale = list(list(0, "blue"), list(0.5, "white"), list(1, "red"))
```

to control the colorbar, or you can set the name of a color palette of `brewer.pal()`, e.g.

```r
colorscale = "RdYlBu"
```